# CMake add prefix to each element of a list

Tags: cmake

In GNU Make I would have written this:

```
DEF=FOO BAR BAZ
CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINIITIONS=$(addprefix -D,$(FOO))
```

Is there an equivalent in CMake other than doing this:

```
macro(addprefix prefix list_name)
   SET(${list_name}_TMP)
   foreach(l ${list_name})
      list(APPEND ${list_name}_TMP ${prefix}${l} )
   endforeach()

   SET(${list_name} ${list_name}_TMP)
   UNSET(${list_name}_TMP)
endmacro(addprefix)

set(APPEND required_definitions FOO BAR BAZ)
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS addprefix(-D required_definitions))
```

CMake is supposed to be easier to use than GNU Make...

Comment: Can you use `target_compile_definitions` with the original list?

Comment: Woh! That is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformulating my previous comment as answer:

```
target_compile_definitions(your_target PUBLIC ${your_list})
```

is probably the CMake command you are looking for.